# Future procurement prediction by seeing past sales

Tags: java, algorithm, prediction

I have interesting problem to solve in my workplace. Initially we wanted to predict the items which we should procure for warehouse before it all gets consumed. I thought this is a very simple problem to solve so i did something related to below:

Schedule a cron job for night which will spawn some threads and they will `calculate the average sales for last one month i.e. suppose 2400 units sold of an item then average sells is 8 per day.` Then see the current stock if the `total stock / avg perday sales(calculated earlier)` is less than some days range than predict for procurement.

mathematically:

```
1.    S1 + S2 + .....+ S30 (sum of all sales in a month)
2.    calculate average: (S1 + S2 + .....+ S30)/30 i.e. AvgSales
3.    IF ( currentStock / AvgSales) < 5 than predict for procurement
```

But there is a major flaw in the approach, if suppose an item was sold on day1 on a heavy number but after that it has no sales at all and it has some stocks also (but not moving), it will show up in the prediction, which is incorrect. So can you please help is finding a proper solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Google "time series forecasting".

Comment: `I thought this is a very simple problem to solve` This was the mistake. This is a science in its own, trend analysis... There are some $100k+ tools for this purpose... The simplest approach is to visualize the raw data to those who do the business aspect, and they can tell, as they have the domain knowledge.